# Convert razor .cshtml files to C# .cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, roslyn

I need to run some analysis on the source code of a web application, including its views, using [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx).

Since it can only parse C# files and not razor views, I planned to convert the views into uncompiled .cs files and then have Roslyn parse that.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the extension package [Razor Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1f6ec6ff-e89b-4c47-8e79-d2d68df894ec) is what you're looking for.

> Generates source code from Razor files (.cshtml files), allowing them to be compiled into your assemblies. Supports MVC, Web Pages and standalone templates.

Comment: Currently, you cannot use RazorGenerator in a .NET Core project.

Answer (score 1):

I am generating `.cs` file from Razor `.cshtml` files with help of [Razor Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidEbbo.RazorGenerator) library.

Generated `cs` files contains line information from the `.cshtml` source files. So if you run your Roslyn analyzer against `.cs` files you can map the source line from `.cs` file back to the original `.cshtml` file.